# What happens to my Dropbox data when my extended storage space expires?

Tags: dropbox

I bought Samsung Galaxy Note tablet and received 48GB of Dropbox storage for two years.
I already had 22GB free storage so I can now use 70GB of Dropbox storage.
After two years, my free storage will decrease back to 22GB. Then what happens to my data? I don't think they will just randomly delete my files to make it 22GB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Dropbox Help Site](https://www.dropbox.com/help/333) you still have access, but you will not be able to sync anything (new or changed files) until you get the space down to whatever you are actually subscribing to.